# using group function excluding few fields - linking many tables without mixing its data with another table - performing queries on dynamic table

Tags: mysql, codeigniter-3

I have few tables of CRM App ,i am writing sql query for displaying summary of all data on dashboard.

lets say there are 3 tables, one is orders which have different client types like local, interstate, international.
other is ecom orders, and the third is expenses ( which includes salary and assets purchase etc)

(Note: this is just example. real data and real tables are very big have lots of joins .. )

there is a field total_amount in all three tables.

i am trying to display : 
`SUM(table1.total_amount) & its COUNT`

- SUM(table1.total_amount) where client types are local, interstate, international. AND its count respectively
- SUM(table1.total_amount) yearly and its Count
- SUM(table1.total_amount) monthly and its Count

NOW i want to select the same from table2 and table3 also.

all these will further sub categorised as sum(table.total_amount) & count(table.total_amount) where status is dispatched/delivered/pending etc
that too overall , yearly and monthly ..

so is this possible in a single query ?

in view at some places i just need to show a only one figure.. and at some places i want to show table array with group by ..

So far i have tried case statement for this , but that makes my query really long,  so i tried writing it without case statement like sum and count so and so and group by a client_id or something .. it gives me correct data.. but as i am using group it doesn't show me over all total in that .. 
which is correct approach for this, ? case statement or sub queries ? 
as i want to write all that in a single query .. or it wont work in single and i have to write separate query and function for each table ??

pleas guide .. any suggestion and examples would be appreciated .

Update: -

["DESCRIBE" of one table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YK61.png)

```
CREATE TABLE `orders` (
 `order_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `order_num` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `client_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `po_num` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `sub_client_name` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `payment_terms` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `payment_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
 `delivery_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
 `order_amount` decimal(10,0) NOT NULL,
 `tax` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
 `total_amount` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
 `order_note` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
 `marketing_by` int(10) NOT NULL,
 `dispatched_by` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `dispatched_on` date DEFAULT NULL,
 `dfrom_store` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `delivered_by` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `delivered_on` date DEFAULT NULL,
 `grn_id` varchar(125) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `order_department` int(10) NOT NULL,
 `order_status` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT '1',
 `payment_status` enum('NR','R') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'NR',
 `transporter_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `transporter_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `transporter_contact` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 `transporter_cost` int(10) NOT NULL,
 `vehicle_num` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `invoice_no` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `excise_tax` int(10) NOT NULL,
 `notes` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `tax_flag` enum('Y','N') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
 `alert_flag` enum('Y','N') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
 `gst_tax_flag` enum('Y','N') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
 `gst_inc_tax_flag` enum('Y','N') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
 `net_margin` int(10) NOT NULL,
 `net_margin_perc` int(10) NOT NULL,
 `on_hold` enum('Y','N') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
 `is_deleted` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `gt_is_deleted` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `created_on` datetime NOT NULL,
 `created_by` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `modified_on` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `modified_by` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`order_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=7733 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

---

UPDATE 2

```
overall_total_amount -- overall_total_count -- over_total_amount_this_year - overall_total_count_this_year
```

yearly_total_orders_amount and count .. that ie. month wise(jan, feb, mar and all) 
monthly_total_orders_amount and count.. (which is date wise per day of the present month)

Total_orders_amount and count client_wise - that is >

```
client_type1 > total_amount_over_all > total_count 

client_type2 > total_amount_over_all > total_count
```

and so on .. 
and same for yearly and monthly like

```
client_type1 > jan_total_amount > total_count
client_type1 > feb_total_amount > total_count
client_type2 > jan_total_amount > total_count
client_type2 > feb_total_amount > total_count
```

the same for monthly in which months will take place of daily dates.

///this is just for one module table but 
i have 12-13 like this .. 
i know how to do this is separate queries and php functions .. but thinking of doing this in single query.. 
as all tables would do the same calculations, just would return different data according to data stored in their table..the fields which i want to calculate also have the same name, so it would be so stupid of me to copy the same query 12-13 times for each table and change the table name in the end to show output ..  there for i am searching a way where i can pull all data required on a dynamic table and assign a id and their respective table name in front of each and then can perform queries on it by double grouping it..
want to show all in separate divs / blocks on single page i.e dashboard page. all tables have total_amount and created, dispatched etc date fields ..

so on dashboard i can call them whenever needed ..  also there would be arrays for some and there would be single field result for some .. is that possible in sql or php to have both in single function/query ? 
like- for sales total there would be only one field giving result and for sales yearly montly or categorywise or clientwise there would be list of arrays .. 
the solution i think is write a single query to displays result something like (not sure what i am saying is possible or not) 
date  --  client_type -- category -- total_amount -- count -- status -- module_group --(dynamic_id)

and then run one more query on this table like
- count all id where client_type is 1 as overall_count_client_type_1
- sum all total_amount where module_group is orders_tables and year is current year group by month (which will output array of months)

i dont know how to create layout of desired output thats why i explained in text..

UPDATE - 3

[output description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YK61.png)

i want an output something like this .. i have date wise data and total in the same table here. and client and status are stored with that particular order which is fetched with the row .
if i get this then want to perform query on this .. Like- sum(total_amount) where year is 2019 and derived_from_table is retail_orders , select all where status is dispatched and derived from table is ecom..

**Update 4**
i have one more query somewhat related to this

```
SELECT
DATE_FORMAT(o.created_on, '%d-%b-%Y') AS retail_daily_date,
            SUM(o.total_amount) as retail_daily_total ,
            COUNT(o.total_amount) as retail_daily_count
        FROM
            orders o
            LEFT JOIN client c ON c.client_id = o.client_id
           WHERE
            YEAR(o.created_on) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())
            AND MONTH(o.created_on) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())
            AND c.client_type = 3
            AND o.is_deleted = 0
                        GROUP BY
          DATE_FORMAT(o.created_on, '%d-%m-%Y') 
        ORDER BY
          DATE_FORMAT(o.created_on, '%d-%Y-%m')
```

it will output daily order totals datewise 
date           total      count
1st jan        5000       10
2nd jan        2000       6

and so on ..

i want same table for all clients.. so each time i write same query and just change the client_type 1, 2, 3, 4, and so on to get result..

how can i do that in a single query ??

Comment: If you show us the schema for the tables that you are talking about it would help to provide you with some assistance

Comment: @RiggsFolly just updated this in the question . .. please check

Comment: its always better to post the text into the question, pictures are not so useful. Specially as that one actually cuts off some columns

Comment: Use `SHOW CREATE TABLE YourTableName;` and then copy/paste to your question

Comment: What are you using to issue this command

Comment: php .. but first i am trying to display all required data in phpmyadmin .. so far i have successfully used case statement , and now trying with without case statement , so that i can have all the data from all other tables and this one too in a single query along with group by client_id, montly, yearly, and overall,

Comment: All you have mentioned is possible, May you please also post what is your expected result will look alike.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai its messy , dont know how to explain it .. but i have output in my mind and tried to explain.. please see update 2 in my edited question ..

Comment: @AnshM, it seems even you are not clear what exactly you want. Take some time and edit question again for your correct expected output in tabular format.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai i know but i dont know how to show this on stackover flow.. as i dont use it much .. and unable to explain . 
can you tell me the solution of what you were thinking the question is ?

Comment: As an alternative, you can draw your result on an excel and then can paste that image here. Please remove all the unnecessary information from the question.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai i have added excel created output pic in the question in update 3. .. . will remove unnecessary information

Comment: After seeing your expected result, I don't think it is possible to achieve this all in single query.

Comment: what should i use then ? any suggestion ?

Comment: @AnkitBajpai please check update 4 .. is this possible ?

Comment: @AnshM, You already have that query with you. You only need to change c.client_type = 3 in the query. What else you need?

Comment: @AnkitBajpai thats the problem ..  i have 10+ clients and 13-14 modules which will use the same query .. i can write it again for different tables.. but here i am fetching data just from one table ..  the whole query and fields and table name everything is same ..  i have to write separate query for each client .. any way i can write all in the same ??

Comment: The maximum extent that i can think of is you can create a procedure having this query wit the client id as parameter and then can call that procedure with different parameter.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai can you please explain with some example. i am not that much expert .

Comment: or if possible can you teach me on screenshare .. so that you can see the project and get the best solution . ?

Comment: You can take the help from https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-stored-procedures.html to create the procedure. For rest you can contact me on ankitbajpai9@yahoo.com

Comment: @AnkitBajpai about update 4 .. how about writing it in Switch CASE statement ? i wrote the code error free. but dont know how to call number of rows on page through it . ex: function- getsales($client_type)- switch($type){case retail : append "1" case : ecom : appned 2 -- then query-> select so and so from table where client_type = ? , $client_type) return query .. 

this works fine with single field data but not working with arrays of rows. . .. am i doing the right way ?

Comment: With many apologies I am only db developer. For PHP related issues you can open a new question.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai i have another sql query issue .. but i am banned by the community to ask more questions .. if you okay to answer me here.. then can i post the issue here in comment section ???

Comment: You can rather mail me on ankit.bajpai9@yahoo.com. The detailed problem with supporting data in tables.